# How to run systemctl service as user

Tags: linux, users

I'm trying to get mpd running as a server. When I `ncpmpc`, I see no songs. This is probably because mpd does not have access to my music folder.

Here is my folder:

```
drwxrwxrwx  4 pi            pi                4096 Jun  2 01:23 Music
```

Here is some of it's content

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi            pi            10624841 Jun  2 01:23 Coldplay - Adventure Of A Lifetime .mp3
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi            pi                4096 Jun  2 01:19 Coldplay - The Best Songs (2016)
```

Mpd is running as a service, I have tried running `sudo mpd` but then I get this error

```
socket: Failed to bind to '0.0.0.0:6600': Address already in use
```

I'm thinking it's because mpd is already running. I also tried this, to stop it:

```
sudo systemctl stop mpd
```

but get this, so maybe that's what stopping `sudo mpd` from running.

```
Warning: Stopping mpd.service, but it can still be activated by:
  mpd.socket
```

This is all a bit confusing for me. I would prefer to run mpd as a service, but don't know what the permissions has to be for that to work. And how to set them up.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to make it into a "user service" by creating an `mpd.service` in `~/.local/share/systemd/user/` and you can enable and start the service by running the following commands without `root`:

```
$ systemctl --user enable mpd.service
$ systemctl --user start mpd.service
```

The service will start running as your user.

Comment: What user should I use then? The same as the owner of the files? Pi in this case?

Comment: Also, can I just create ./local and it's subfolders if they are not there?

Comment: `~/.local` not `~/local`. In case you're not aware, `~` means your home folder which is `/home/<username>` or `/home/pi` in this case.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I meant /.local (/home/pi/local), it's not there, tried cd .local and ls -a, only folder is .ssh.

Comment: Yeah, just create it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: okay and what should the content mpd.service look like? Also I tried setting the ueser to mpd for the music folder, sudo chown -R mpd Music, didn't work though.